# twitter search api with jquery error

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter, jsonp

I need to request a twitter search with jquery using twitter api. After read [documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3a-search) I write this code:

```
  $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=myFunction&q=stackoverflow");

   function myFunction(r) {
       console.log(r);
    }
```

search.json Failed to load resource> When the page is executed, Google Chrome show this error on Console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=myFunction&q=stackoverflow.
>   Origin http://localhost/twitter is not
>   allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   search.json Failed to load resource

what is the problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to write it a bit differently, like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=stackoverflow", 
  function (r) {
    console.log(r);
});
```

To trigger JSONP it's looking for *explicitly* `callback=?`, which isn't in your named function version.  To use the named callback, you're better off going with the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) full version:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=stackoverflow",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "myFunction"
});

function myFunction(r) { console.log(r); }
```

Comment: i wish someone would document this more properly, i spent an hour trying to figure out why im getting access denied!

Comment: Nick Craver saved my day (again): remember to use *jsonp* not *json* for the `dataType` :)

Comment: Looks like Twitter has made some changes and caused this answer to no longer hold true.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a bit more to the answer you can use the following code to display text within each returned tweet.

```
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=stackoverflow",

function(data){

for (i=0; i<data.results.length; i++){

$("#tweets").append("<p><strong>Text: </strong>" + data.results[i].text + "<BR/>" + "<p><strong>Created at: </strong>" + data.results[i].created_at +"</p><br /><br />");

}
});
```

Then within your body html put the following div

```
<div id="tweets"></div>
```