# jquery: save form response from hidden iframe to variable

Tags: jquery, forms, variables, iframe

heyho,

i have a form which i send to a script on action. the response is stored to a hidden iframe in pre-tags. i want to store the html-text answer to a variable with jquery. but the question is how and when :-)! onsubmit is to early.. can you help?

```
<form id="search" action="http://xyzsearchurl"  target="result">
<input type="text" name="qparam" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<iframe id="result" name="result" src="#" style="display:none;"></iframe>

$('#search').submit(function(){
    alert($('#result pre').html());
});
```

any ideas how to get the Text form the pre tag AFTER get the response?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can register the onload event from the iframe and then read the content.
Note: this will only work if the frame is loaded from the same server (same origin policy)

```
$('#search').submit(function(){
   //register load event of iframe...
   $('#result').load(function() {
     $("#result").contents().find("what you need...");
   });
});
```

Comment: hey daniel, its unfortunately not the same origin (social media api). do you know another way? i thought abot a timeout, but that is not that "beautyful"

Comment: Read upon JSONP requests, but the other server you are using has to support it. If not you will have to use a proxy on your server side...

Comment: hey daniel, see this [twitter post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996438/twitter-search-api-with-jquery-error). this is exactly my problem :-) i did not find it yesterday. $.getJSON() works fine, but i have problems with using the declared $.ajax() solution which I would prefer. I do not know how to get access to the answer (which is like: myCallbackFunction({JSONresponse}) as I can see in firebug, but nothing happens when I try to console.log() the results