# Jquery & JSON twitter feed not working when uploaded to server

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I am trying to get a twitter feed working using CSS Tricks method:

http://css-tricks.com/build-your-own-social-home/

With a few alterations. Everything is working fine in the live preview on dreamweaver, but when it uploads to the server nothing appears. I have done some searching around the other questions already and cannot come up with anything that relates to my problem directly

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?include_entities=true&user_id=913166730&count=5', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
        $('#news').append('<div class="story"><h3 style="margin:0px;"><a style="color:#000; text-decoration:none;" href="http://twitter.com/TheHopperLane" title="The Hopper Lane">@Thehopperlane</a></h3><p>' + item.text.linkify() + '</p><p style="font-size:12px;">' + relative_time(item.created_at) + '</p></div>');
    });

});
function relative_time(time_value) {
    var values = time_value.split(" ");
    time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
    var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
    var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
    var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
    delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

    var r = '';
    if (delta < 60) {
        r = 'a minute ago';
    } else if(delta < 120) {
        r = 'couple of minutes ago';
    } else if(delta < (45*60)) {
        r = (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
    } else if(delta < (90*60)) {
        r = 'an hour ago';
    } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
        r = '' + (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + ' hours ago';
    } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
        r = '1 day ago';
    } else {
        r = (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() + ' days ago';
    }
    return r;
}
String.prototype.linkify = function() {
    return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/, function(m) {
        return m.link(m);
    }).replace(/\B#([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(hashtag) {
        return '<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23'+hashtag.substring(1)+'">'+hashtag+'</a>';
    }).replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(screenname) {
        return '<a href="http://twitter.com/'+screenname+'">'+screenname+'</a>';
    });
};
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="news">
<h2>Latest News</h2>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I can provide links to the site in question if necessary

EDIT: It seems that everything is down simply to the following error!

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?include_entities=true&user_id=913166730&count=5. Origin http://thehopperlane.co.uk is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."
```

I can't believe I didn't catch this sooner! However, I have left the question open as it is not resolved on this site as far as I am aware. People make mention of including callback=? and using JSONP and not just JSON, however these fixes no longer seem to work (notice the last comment on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996438/twitter-search-api-with-jquery-error)

Comment: Links to the site would be very helpful.

Comment: www.thehopperlane.co.uk/news.php
The particular page ive linked to is hidden on the site for now

Comment: Are any errors appearing in the console? What have you done when trying to debug this?

Comment: Upon validation it has a fit about the < signs in the date/time part saying "character < is the first character of a delimiter but occured as data"

Comment: I have fixed all the validation errors by moving the above script into an external js file.